# Windows Home Server Backup for the Enterprise

Tags: backup, windows-home-server

I recently setup a Windows Home Server, and found the backup functionality to be quite good for my home network.  Does Microsoft produce anything similar for Windows Server?  I'd love to be able to tell my server to backup all clients in the domain, the same way Home Server does.  I'm specifically looking for a solution that works with Server 2003, although I'd be open to upgrading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a grand fan of of WHS's backup mechanism.  I have done a lot of looking and the closest thing that I have found is System Center Data Protection Manager.

http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/dataprotectionmanager/en/us/default.aspx

It looks a little pricey, but it seems to be the ticket.

What I would like is WHS Profesional.  Let me purchase CAL's to allow me to backup more than 10 machines.  I have a ton of small clients that would love that functionality, and just cannot(or very reluctant) afford the full blown System Center server setup and all the software/hardware costs that the system would require.